# R write.table does not write 2 matrices on the same file

Tags: r

I have 2 matrices x and y. I would like to write them on the same csv file in following orders:  matrix x, "some text", matrix y. I used the function write.table to append the file. However, there is only the y matrix is written while the x matrix is missing. I notice that if I remove "some text" among the 2 commands write.table, both matrices will be printed out properly. Actually, I want to keep "some text" before printing the matrix y since this will help me to identify my result in the big data test. Do you have any suggestions? Thank you.

```
rm(list=ls())
cat("\014")

file_ext="csv"
output_file = paste("result", file_ext, sep = ".")

(x <- matrix(1, nrow = 3, ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE))
(y <- matrix(2, nrow = 3, ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE))

sink(output_file)
#------------------------------------------------------------
cat("The results are:",sep="\n")

#write the x matrix. PROBLEM: the x matrix is not printed out
cat("The x matrix",append =TRUE)
cat("\n")
write.table(x, file=output_file, sep=",", col.names = F, row.names = F, append = TRUE)

#write the y matrix. 
cat("The y matrix",append =TRUE)
cat("\n")
write.table(y, file=output_file, sep=",", col.names = F, row.names = F, append = TRUE)

sink()
file.show(output_file) #show the file in directory
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
The results are:    
The x matrix    
1   1
1   1
1   1
The y matrix    
2   2
2   2
2   2
```

Code:

```
rm(list=ls())

file_ext="csv"
output_file = paste("result", file_ext, sep = ".")

(x <- matrix(1, nrow = 3, ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE))
(y <- matrix(2, nrow = 3, ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE))

sink(output_file)

cat("The results are:\nThe x matrix\n")
write.table(x,row.names=FALSE,col.names=FALSE,sep=",")

cat("The y matrix\n")
write.table(y,row.names=FALSE,col.names=FALSE,sep=",")

sink()
file.show(output_file) #show the file in directory
```

Comment: Yes, it is my expected result. Your fix works perfectly. Thank you very much.